# Statistics for rounded data

Tags: hypothesis-testing, normal-distribution, goodness-of-fit, censoring, interval-censoring

I wonder about the existence of "standard" statistical procedures for rounded (log)normal data. Indeed, in my work I often encounter rounded data which potentially cause some problems: "awful" qqplots, zeros for lognormal data... Do there exist in the literature some theoretical studies of usual statistical procedures (such as goodness-of-fit, t-test, ...) for rounded data ?

EDIT: I have just discovered the MCMCtobit() function in the [MCMCpack R package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/MCMCpack/MCMCpack.pdf): *Gaussian Linear Regression with a Censored Dependent Variable; the dependent variable may be censored from below, from above, or both.* In my case the dependent variable is censored by its rounded value, hence the censoring is data-dependent. Is it correct to use MCMCtobit() in this context ?

EDIT2 : Now I have discovered the [grouped R package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/grouped/grouped.pdf). I think this is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for the comments given below!

Comment: QQplots are not recommended for discrete distributions. There is a HUGE literature about dealing with rounded observations. Use also "grouped data" in your keywords. [link](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=goodness+of+fit%2C+grouped)

Comment: This paper discusses the effect of rounding on testing for normality:  http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/02664760903143925

Comment: Thanks to both of you. @Procrastinator: the animated Google search is very amazing :)

Comment: In fact, the goodness-of-fit is not my main interest. For example I am more interested in the t-test for two rounded samples.

Comment: Charles Manski has a research program on rounding, mostly focused on bounds.