# taking log of sales when many observations are 0 or close?

Tags: r, econometrics

I am currently attempting to replicate an Econ paper in R, which claims that they take the natural log of net sales. Many of the observations however are either 0 or very close to 0. What is the general procedure in this case?

Thank you and I appreciate your help,

Comment: ssdecontrol posted a great answer to a related question here: http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/210160/26338

Comment: It matters whether net sales is a regressor or response.  Note that in many situations, taking the log of any net value is worthless in modeling because the net may be negative.  Even net sales can be negative (due to returns).  For general methods of dealing with logarithms, please [search our site](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=log+zero+regression+-likelihood+-interpretation).

Answer (score 1):

There are several alternatives:

1. Replace zero with a small positive number, like a penny. This is very easy. The drawback of this approach is that the results can be sensitive to what you replace with. Secondly, you may care about net sales, not the log thereof, so you will have to deal with retransforming back to the original scale.
2. Use a robust-to-heteroskedasticity poisson model. See [here](http://blog.stata.com/2011/08/22/use-poisson-rather-than-regress-tell-a-friend/) for why this works nicely. Naturally handles zeros, no re-transformations to deal with.
3. Use something like a Tobit or a two-part model. The first (with
   logged sales) would be the appropriate if the same set of factors is
   affecting (in exactly the same way) whether or not an observation is
   at zero and what its value is when not zero. In many economic
   contexts this does not make much sense. For example, if you model
   expenditure on vacation and the covariate of interest is the number
   of kids, the Tobit would not work well. Having more children
   typically makes people less likely to go on vacation (negative
   effect), but conditional on going, the expenditure would be larger
   (positive effect). If the zeros stem from a choice not to sell a
   product or from a mixture of non-sellers and zero sales among sellers, a Tobit may
   not work. In that case, something like a two-part model or one of
   its extensions should be estimated.