# Infinite values

Tags: reporting

I am going to log transform a scale due to extreme skewness; I am using RStudio for my analyses (linear regression). Some of the values computed are "-Inf" or infinite values.  To address this, I was thinking of adding 1 to my log10 code: y =log10(x + 1). Previous posts indicate that this would address my problem. Are there specific guidelines for reporting my results? Do I have to "back transform" anything during interpretation?

Comment: Before you do this, you might want to study your options and their potential effects on the results.  See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/30728 *inter alia.*  There's a huge difference between transforming the explanatory and response variables, too: the answer to your question depends on which variable you transform.

Comment: Also note that back-transformation will be impossible, which greatly reduces the interpretability of the result.

Comment: @Knarpie Could you elaborate?  Since the function $x\to \log_{10}(x+1)=y$ is explicitly invertible and surjective, you must have in mind something different than just finding $x$ in terms of $y.$

Comment: Yes sorry, I am referring to the interpretability of the regression coefficients in function of the original variable