# How to interpret a Log Normal Distribution

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, lognormal-distribution

I have a dataset with 3 columns that are found out to be log-normally distributed. I am a little bit confused about how can I draw the conclusion in a log-normal distribution similar to Normal distribution(68 95 99.5 rule).

I have attached the screenshot of my log-normal distribution. But I am unable to interpret it.
Here I used Q-Q plot to check if the data is log-normal
[image]

Comment: Your data cannot be log-normally distributed because it has an atom at zero (in all 3 cases). What exact question are you trying to answer about your data?

Comment: @ChrisHaug I know it is not exactly log-normal. But if you remove those data points then it will be almost log-normal. I just want to know how can u interpret the data when it's log-normal distributed

Comment: Setting aside whether it is appropriate to just remove those zeros,, "interpret the data" is very vague. Again, what are you trying to find out about your data?

Comment: I believe your interpretation may be faulty: these plots are much closer to censored Normal distributions than to any lognormal.  For one explanation of how they arise, please see https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/30749/919, where (near the end) strikingly similar plots appear.