# Negative forecast value using ARIMA from fable and NaNs warning using ARIMA

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, arima, box-jenkins

My data set is a weekly data that contains two variables Production and Shipment. Production is the independent variable and Shipment is the dependent variable. First I'm trying to forecast Production values and use that as a regressor to forecast Shipment variable.

I had two issues

1. When generating Production forecasts - the last step forecast (h=4) was a negative value. If it was zero  then it would be more accurate than having a huge negative value as on that week the actual would most likely be zero.
2. When fitting the forecast model for Shipment variable- using Production data and fourier term I get a NaNs warning despite using Automated ARIMA with stepwise=False, approx= False.

Could you anyone please help me with these two queries.
Thank you for the support

````
Original.df<-structure(list(YearWeek = c("201901", "201902", "201903", "201904", 
"201905", "201906", "201907", "201908", "201909", "201910", "201911", 
"201912", "201913", "201914", "201915", "201916", "201917", "201918", 
"201919", "201920", "201921", "201922", "201923", "201924", "201925", 
"201926", "201927", "201928", "201929", "201930", "201931", "201932", 
"201933", "201934", "201935", "201936", "201937", "201938", "201939", 
"201940", "201941", "201942", "201943", "201944", "201945", "201946", 
"201947", "201948", "201949", "201950", "201951", "201952", "202001", 
"202002", "202003", "202004", "202005", "202006", "202007", "202008", 
"202009", "202010", "202011", "202012", "202013", "202014", "202015", 
"202016", "202017", "202018", "202019", "202020", "202021", "202022", 
"202023", "202024", "202025", "202026", "202027", "202028", "202029", 
"202030", "202031", "202032", "202033", "202034", "202035", "202036", 
"202037", "202038", "202039", "202040", "202041", "202042", "202043", 
"202044", "202045", "202046", "202047", "202048", "202049", "202050", 
"202051", "202052", "202053", "202101", "202102", "202103", "202104", 
"202105", "202106", "202107", "202108", "202109", "202110", "202111", 
"202112", "202113", "202114", "202115", "202116", "202117", "202118", 
"202119", "202120", "202121", "202122", "202123", "202124", "202125", 
"202126", "202127", "202128", "202129", "202130", "202131", "202132", 
"202133", "202134", "202135", "202136", "202137", "202138", "202139", 
"202140", "202141", "202142", "202143", "202144", "202145", "202146", 
"202147", "202148", "202149", "202150", "202151", "202152", "202201", 
"202202", "202203"), Shipment = c(399, 1336, 1018, 1126, 1098, 
1235, 1130, 1258, 897, 1333, 1221, 1294, 1628, 1611, 1484, 1238, 
1645, 1936, 1664, 1482, 2060, 1964, 1875, 1645, 2039, 1640, 733, 
1764, 1639, 1968, 1692, 1677, 1542, 1299, 1328, 1130, 1741, 1929, 
1843, 1427, 1467, 1450, 1041, 1238, 1721, 1757, 1813, 1001, 1208, 
1916, 1435, 540, 681, 1436, 1170, 938, 1206, 1648, 1169, 1311, 
1772, 1333, 1534, 1365, 1124, 846, 732, 753, 1266, 1652, 1772, 
1814, 1649, 1191, 1298, 986, 1296, 1066, 777, 1041, 1388, 1289, 
1097, 1356, 1238, 1732, 1109, 1104, 1155, 1334, 1094, 770, 1411, 
1304, 1269, 1093, 1096, 1121, 943, 695, 1792, 2033, 1586, 768, 
685, 993, 1406, 1246, 1746, 1740, 938, 160, 1641, 1373, 1023, 
1173, 1611, 928, 1038, 1009, 1274, 1369, 1231, 1053, 1163, 880, 
870, 1131, 882, 1143, 632, 394, 510, 543, 535, 824, 874, 591, 
512, 448, 247, 452, 470, 747, 545, 639, 326, 414, 604, 640, 458, 
272, 524, 589, 666, 217, 215, 348, 537, 466), Production = c(794, 
1400, 1505, 1055, 1396, 1331, 1461, 1623, 1513, 1667, 1737, 1264, 
1722, 1587, 2094, 1363, 2007, 1899, 1749, 1693, 1748, 1455, 2078, 
1702, 1736, 1885, 860, 1372, 1716, 1290, 1347, 1451, 1347, 1409, 
1203, 1235, 1397, 1557, 1406, 1451, 1704, 670, 1442, 1336, 1611, 
1401, 1749, 744, 1558, 1665, 1317, 0, 441, 1351, 1392, 1180, 
1447, 1265, 1485, 1494, 1543, 1581, 1575, 1597, 1191, 1386, 889, 
1002, 1573, 1380, 1346, 1243, 1009, 965, 1051, 905, 1094, 1194, 
891, 1033, 921, 880, 1135, 1058, 1171, 1022, 956, 880, 902, 983, 
1014, 945, 1021, 1058, 1191, 1139, 1292, 573, 1173, 514, 1292, 
1310, 1239, 0, 0, 1182, 1028, 1028, 1196, 1214, 1045, 256, 1451, 
1344, 1352, 1257, 1444, 786, 1369, 1185, 1262, 1025, 949, 1051, 
941, 727, 911, 951, 987, 1136, 884, 770, 959, 1102, 1109, 1098, 
988, 983, 1002, 904, 1147, 1149, 919, 1058, 1112, 479, 1028, 
1154, 1126, 1155, 1208, 536, 839, 1178, 1225, 539, 0, 862, 839, 
873)), row.names = c(NA, 160L), class = "data.frame")

# Converting the df to accomodate leap year for weekly observations
Original.df <- Original.df %>%
  mutate(
    isoweek =stringr::str_replace(YearWeek, "^(\\d{4})(\\d{2})$", "\\1-W\\2-1"),
    date = ISOweek::ISOweek2date(isoweek)
  )

#creating test and train data
Original.train.df <- Original.df %>%
  filter(date >= "2018-12-31", date <= "2021-11-22")

Original.test.df <- Original.df %>%
  filter(date >= "2021-11-29", date <= "2021-12-27")

Shipment.Test.df<- Original.test.df %>%
  dplyr::select(-YearWeek, -Production, -date,-isoweek) %>% as_tibble()

# splitting the original train data to contain only Week, Dependent and Independent variables
Total.train.df<-Original.train.df %>%
  mutate(Week.1 = yearweek(ISOweek::ISOweek(date))) %>%
  dplyr::select(-YearWeek,-date,-isoweek) %>%
  as_tsibble(index = Week.1)

#Model.1-Fitting forecast model(Arima with Fourier terms) to Production.qty 

bestfit.Prod.1.AICc <- Inf

for(K in seq(25)){
  fit.Prod.1 <- Total.train.df %>% 
    model(ARIMA(Production ~ fourier(K = K), stepwise = FALSE, approximation = FALSE))
  
  if(purrr::pluck(glance(fit.Prod.1), "AICc") < bestfit.Prod.1.AICc)
  {
    bestfit.Prod.1.AICc <- purrr::pluck(glance(fit.Prod.1), "AICc")
    bestfit.Prod.1<- fit.Prod.1
    bestK.Prod.1 <- K
  }
}

bestK.Prod.1
glance(bestfit.Prod.1)

#Model.1-Forecasting Net.Production.Qty for 4 steps using the fitted model above
Forecast.Prod.1<-bestfit.Prod.1 %>% 
  forecast(h = 4)

#Here I get the 4th step forecasted point as -146
Final.Prod.1<-Forecast.Prod.1$.mean

#Model.1-Fitting forecast model(Arima with Fourier terms) and 
#Production training data(actuals) as regressors to Shipment Qty

bestfit.Shipment.1.AICc <- Inf

for(K in seq(25)){
  fit.Shipment.1 <- Total.train.df %>% 
    model(ARIMA(Shipment ~Production + fourier(K = K),stepwise = FALSE))
  
  if(purrr::pluck(glance(fit.Shipment.1), "AICc") < bestfit.Shipment.1.AICc)
  {
    bestfit.Shipment.1.AICc <- purrr::pluck(glance(fit.Shipment.1), "AICc")
    bestfit.Shipment.1<- fit.Shipment.1
    bestK.Shipment.1 <- K
  }
}

#above model shows NaNs warning
bestK.Shipment.1
glance(bestfit.Shipment.1)

```
````

Comment: ARIMA presupposes normally distributed innovations, so it has no compunctions about outputting negative forecasts: https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Barima%5D+negative+forecast. Regarding your second question, I have to admit that the added complexity of tidyverse code instead of plain R raises a hurdle that is simply too steep for me. Maybe some other user who is more versed in this dialect can chime in.

Comment: Thank you, Eliminating Fourier terms from my model eliminates the negative error and the Nans warning message..Also this is specific to the test data as it falls on December last week which tends to have zero value which in turn generates the above two issues.Do I have a better solution as opposed to Fourier transform to address local seasonality since the data is weekly

Comment: You could take a look at [Dokumentov & Hyndman's STR method](https://arxiv.org/abs/2009.05894v2), which is implemented in the `stR` package for R.

Comment: Thank you for introducing me with STR package, seems like an intuitive package with lot of applications. But in my case, taking log transformations solved this issue- log(x + 1) on both the variables resolved the negative forecast outputs. Since I'm using fable it helped me back transform the forecast to have the forecasted mean

Answer (score 0):

Taking log transformations solved this issue- log(x + 1) on both the variables resolved the negative forecast outputs. Since I'm using fable it helped me back transform the forecast to have the forecasted mean.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Although this method *can* work, it is *ad hoc.*  For better solutions along this line see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/30728.